# child gird checkbox would not update correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested grid with checkbox in both grid. The checkbox in parent grid has a OnCheckedChanged event to check all checkbox in the parent grid, and another to check all checkbox in the child grid with checkbox in each row.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSelect" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvSelect_DataBound"
              BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ItemNumber">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="RecordUID" SortExpression="RecordUID" HeaderText="RecordUID" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="Images/plus.png" id="ExpandRows" class="expand" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelectExpand" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSelectExpand" runat="server" Width="350px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Slab">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectExpand" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectExpand_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slab" SortExpression="Slab" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Slab" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" SortExpression="Size" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Size" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sqft" SortExpression="Sqft" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Sqft" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Block" SortExpression="Block" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Block" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Totalweight" SortExpression="Totalweight" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Totalweight" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        </Columns>
                        <RowStyle ForeColor="#663399" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" BackColor="#990000" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="XX-Small" Text="Select All Slabs"
                              OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Bundle" SortExpression="Bundle" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="Bundle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNumber" SortExpression="ItemNumber" 
            ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ItemNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDescription" SortExpression="ItemDescription" 
            ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ItemDesc" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="whse" SortExpression="whse" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="Warehouse" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NumSlabs" SortExpression="NumSlabs" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="NumSlabs" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QtyTiedUp" SortExpression="QtyTiedUp" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="QtyTiedUp" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#663399" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" BackColor="#990000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Here are my code behind for the OnCheckedChanged

**CS**

```
protected void chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)gvSelect.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkSelectAll");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSelect.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true)
        {
            ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ChkBoxRows.Checked = false;
        }
        bool status = ChkBoxRows.Checked;

        GridView gvSelectExpand = (GridView)row.FindControl("gvSelectExpand");
        foreach (GridViewRow gvSelectExpandRow in gvSelectExpand.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkSelectExpand = (CheckBox)gvSelectExpandRow.FindControl("chkSelectExpand");
            if (status)
                chkSelectExpand.Checked = true;
            else
                chkSelectExpand.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}

protected void chkSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ckb.NamingContainer;

    CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
    bool status = ChkBoxRows.Checked;
    GridView gvSelectExpand = (GridView)row.FindControl("gvSelectExpand");

    foreach (GridViewRow gvSelectExpandRow in gvSelectExpand.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkSelectExpand = (CheckBox)gvSelectExpandRow.FindControl("chkSelectExpand");
        if (status)
            chkSelectExpand.Checked = true;
        else
            chkSelectExpand.Checked = false;
    }
}

protected void chkSelectExpand_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ;
}
```

**Question**

The issue is

- when I have the chkSelect(checkbox in parent grid row) checked, if I tried to uncheck 1 or more of the chkSelectExpand(checkbox in child grid), it will do a postback and end up checked all checkbox in that child grid again.
- If the chkSelect is not checked, I do not have this issue.

However the postback doesn't triggers chkSelect_CheckedChanged, I put a breakpoint by the function in debug so I can be sure about it.

How do I fix this issue? Please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhat an answer to my own question, and it has to do with how the child grid is displayed.

The following code hide the **true child grid** in the cell of the parent grid. The reason I call it the true child grid is cause if I perform the same action on this grid, everything works as expected, right, and functional.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSelectExpand" runat="server" Style="display: none">
```

I believe it has to do with how the expandable panel works, which is the following code

```
<img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="Images/plus.png" id="ExpandRows" class="expand" />
```

Marking the true child grid cg1, expandable grid cg2. When the checkbox of the parent grid is checked, updating the checkbox in cg1 will also update cg2, but not the other way around. Meaning cg2 is a mirror, or a one way pointer to cg1 that just won't update the true child grid.

If anyone has other suggestion or answer please correct me. I am posting my finding here just for anyone stumble upon the same issue and hopefully he/she will not waste much time as I did.